# Superfluous text each time mate-terminal is opened

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-mate

Whenever I open a mate-terminal, I get superfluous text.

It's the same text every time. ?

Is there a way to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Presumably you have added a `ffmpeg` command to one of your shell startup files - you will need to locate it, and remove or comment out the command

Comment: @steeldriver There is nothing in my Startup Applications that uses ffmpeg.

Comment: not Startup Applications - I was referring to **shell** initialization (`~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or their equivalents if your shell is something other than bash)

Comment: Nothing in any of those. @steeldriver

Comment: @fixit7 It could also be a file that's being `source`d (or `.` as an alias of source) into one of those files (including nested sourcing, like A sourcing B, which sources C, and etc ad nauseum), which runs the code in the sourced file immediately. So, you may need to look deeper than just into those files themselves to fix or remove the offending code.

Comment: @l3l_aze I will need more details so I know where to start?

Comment: Use `bash -x` on your startup files, and you'll see everything!

Comment: @waltinator Not the worst idea, but could potentially cause problems. Running `grep -FHn "ffmpeg" "$HOME/dotfilename"` with each of the dotfiles should lead directly to the file + line if it's in one of them, and could be changed from "ffmpeg" to "source" to find any other files if there are any source'd into them. Haven't figured out how to find the `.` version of "source", but obviously that would be possible somehow.

Comment: So do I put bash -x in front of every startup item like/usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-immediately etc? @waltinator

Comment: @waltinator I removed ffmpeg. And installed avconv. Now this shows up in my terminal. Command 'ffmpeg' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install ffmpeg  # version 4.1.4, or
sudo apt  install ffmpeg

See 'snap info ffmpeg' for additional versions.
ffmpeg is like an alien. :-(

Comment: I had alias mp42mp3=MOV="$";FILENAME=$(basename "${MOV// /_}" | sed 's/(.)-.*/\1/').mp3;ffmpeg -i "${MOV}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 "${FILENAME}" in .bash_aliases. Once it was removed my problem was solved